# Хранить ли в базе данных адреса файлов?

Tags: sql, база-данных, файлы

Нужна система, при которой по имени базы данных, имени таблицы и id нужной строки можно было бы получить соответствующее этой строке изображения.

Вижу 3 варианта:
1) хранить сами изображения в базе данных
2) создать в таблице поле и хранить там адреса нужных изображений
3) хранить изображения в папке с адресом вида **files/**`database`**/**`table`**/**`id`

Сейчас пользуюсь третьим вариантом. И всё бы ничего, но в интернете много раз натыкался на подобный вопрос и ответом всегда был второй вариант.
Так вот, в чём плюсы/минусы второго и третьего вариантов (первый по понятным причинам отпадает) и почему все советуют именно второй?

Comment: Второй. Потому, что если Вам нужно вывести картинку на сайте к примеру, Вам нужен абсолютный URL путь, который будет построет в зависимости от Вашего контроллера, и подставится только имя изображения. Удобство

Comment: Да третий явно быстрее работает, не надо вообще обращаться к БД. Правда надо делать так что бы в одной папке было не более 1000 файлов/папкок. Иначе доступ начинает дико тормозить. Лучше делать несколько папок типа `table/id1`, `table/id2` и т.п. и файлы внутрь помещать по какому нибудь простому алгоритму типа остатка от деления ID на количество таких папок

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не знаю почему советуют второй, третий логичней и гибче. Представьте, что вам захотелось поменять хранилище. В третьем варианте - это всего лишь смена одной строки в конфиге (надеюсь, вы не хардкодите путь?).

А у первого особых плюсов просто нет. Разве что целостность хранилища всех данных, но это сомнительное преимущество.

Comment: хранить файлы из разных баз данных (т.е. приложений) в одной директории?

Comment: @Etki, да и из одной базы в одном каталоге хранить не всегда хорошо. Вариантов разнесения по каталогам может быть много. Но принципиально это схему не меняет. Например, `storage => { base => /var/storage, component1 => /subdir1, ...}` и дальше по потребностям.

Answer (score 1):

Я голосую за **второй**. Представьте что адреса к картинкам разлетелись по всему интернету и пользователи обращаются к вам по ссылкам вида /directory/1/image/5

Само собой работает простой селект из базы - там лежит абсолютный путь к картинке.

Храня ссылки в базе данных легко их поменять - хоть скриптом, хоть просто апдейтом. Можно даже какие то ссылки поменять на внешние. Можно папки объединить или наоборот разбить на 10 штук - главное просто делать это скриптом, одновременно обновляя базу.

Можно часть картинок положить на один винт, а часть картинок доставать снаружи по http. Представьте что нужно сохранить 5 млрд картинок, а на веб сервер влазит от силы миллион? Никакая папочная структура не поможет - нужно будет отдать в ответ картинку, полученную с *другого* сервера по адресу, хранящемуся в базе.

При хранении файлов такой гибкости нет и не будет. Структура файловой системы останется с вами навечно.